# Title of anime where the protagonist is a vampire queen?

Tags: story-identification, anime, vampire

The female lead is a vampire queen and there are two groups one who want to protect and one who wants to kill her. This story involves both werewolves and vampires they all ends up loving her. I think her hair colour is brown and when she gets angry her hair would turn red and she becomes super powerful.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: It could be Blood+, not putting it down as an answer since I don't have time to come up with any references

Answer (score 4):

[*Dance in the Vampire Bund*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dance_in_the_Vampire_Bund)

This might be the series you are thinking of. It has a female vampire lead and her body guard is a werewolf.

Plot synopsis taken from Wikipedia:

> The story revolves around Mina Țepeș, Princess-Ruler of all vampires, and her werewolf protector Akira Kaburagi Regendorf. Like other vampires, Mina has been in hiding with her people for many years. Seeking to end centuries of isolation, Mina gains permission to create a special district for vampires called "The Bund" off the coast of Tokyo, Japan by paying off the entire national debt of the Japanese government with her family's vast wealth.
>
> Following a discussion show where known vampire movie actor Seiichi Hirai (who was revealed to be an actual vampire) is killed by her during his rampage, Mina reveals to the world the existence of vampires while mentioning her desire for both races to live together as they are residing on "The Bund". However, tensions run high as fearful humans and extremist vampire factions begin to interfere with Mina's wish for peace with the human world. This causes Mina and Akira to defend "The Bund" from these attackers.

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166344/anime-with-a-werewolf-protecting-a-little-vampire-girl-because-his-lineage-swore